# How to Run MQTT-Broker and -Clients in Different Docker Containers?

Tags: linux, docker, mqtt

I need to have a MQTT-broker running in a Docker container and then two clients (one sender and one reciever) in two additional Docker containers. The broker is set to listen to port 1883, so my understanding is, that all three containers need to map the hosts port 1883 in order to be able to send and recieve messages.

Unforutantely, this doesn't work, as every host-port can only be mapped once. Is there a way to fix this? Or am I just doing it wrong?

I use [Mosquitto](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto) as the broker. The sender is a NodeRED-flow and the reciever is a .Net application I wrote myself. I'm using Linux containers on a Linux host.

Answer (score 0):

By default Docker uses the [bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/) network driver (see [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) for more info). If you are running in this mode each container is, by default, added to the [default bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network).

Assuming that the above sums up your configuration (all defaults) then there is no need to map any host ports because the containers can communicate using the bridge network.

Below is a simplified `docker-compose.yaml` (see the [go paho repo](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/blob/master/autopaho/examples/docker/docker-compose.yml) for the full thing) demonstrating this. Note that the config for `pub` references `tcp://mosquitto:1883` and sub `ws://mosquitto:80` - docker will resolve `mosquitto` to the `mosquitto` containers network interface.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./binds/mosquitto/config
        target: /mosquitto/config
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./binds/mosquitto/data
        target: /mosquitto/data
      - type: bind
        source: ./binds/mosquitto/log
        target: /mosquitto/log
  pub:
    build:
      dockerfile: publisher/dockerfile
    environment:
      pubdemo_serverURL: tcp://mosquitto:1883
  sub:
    build:
      dockerfile: subscriber/dockerfile
    environment:
      subdemo_serverURL: ws://mosquitto:80
```

Note that even if want to access Mosquitto via the host interface you would only need to map port `1883` to the Mosquitto container (because that is the container listening for a connection).